# Detailed report about site collection

Tags: 2010, reporting

Our business wants detailed reports about our site collection use, size, traffic etc, much more detailed than the reports that are under web analytics. What are the best practices that cover this topic? Is there an out-of-the box solution, or do we need to build our own?

Answer (score 0):

The audit feature of Microsoft SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online let you track user actions on a sites content types, lists, libraries, list items, and library files within your site collections. Knowing who has done what with which information is critical for many business requirements, such as regulatory compliance and records management.

To Enable audit report in SharePoint

- Go to site settings > Site collection Administration

[image]

- Configure your settings

[image]

- Go back to Audit Log Report , to generate your report

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I am aware of the audit feature, but unfortunately, this is not flexible enough for us (or I need to learn more). Like I cannot filter for a given site under a collection (only list), or specific file types, and cannot show facts, like the size of all pdf reports under a given site, also, the output is an excel sheet, and not presentation-ready report.